# Invoke callback method

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm trying to make a nice AJAX interface, loosely adapted to Todd Motto's Atomic.JS (http://toddmotto.com/writing-a-standalone-ajax-xhr-javascript-micro-library/). My adaption isn't working, however. The problem: when using the function like so

```
ajax.post(url, data)
    .success(function(x) {
        console.log('success',x);
    })
    .error(function(x) {
        console.log('error',x);
    });
```

The AJAX function can't 'reach' the error method, while the success behaves perfectly. When I only write the error function when it's called upon it does work perfectly, though. E.g. like so:

```
ajax.post(url, data)
    .error(function(x) {
        console.log('error', x);
    });
```

Here's my AJAX method

```
var ajax = (function() {

    var parse = function(req) {
        var result;
        try {
            result = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        } catch (e) {
            result = req.responseText;
        }
        return [result, req];
    };

    var xhr = function(type, url, data) {
        var methods = {
            success: function() {},
            error: function() {}
        };
        var XHR = XMLHttpRequest || ActiveXObject;
        var request = new XHR('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
        request.open(type, url, true);
        request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState === 4) {
                if (request.status === 200) {
                    methods.success.apply(methods, parse(request));
                } else {
                    methods.error.apply(methods, parse(request));
                }
            }
        };
        request.send(data);
        return {
            success: function(callback) {
                methods.success = callback;
                return methods;
            },
            error: function(callback) {
                methods.error = callback;
                return methods;
            }
        };
    };

    return {
        get: function(url) {
            return xhr('GET', url);
        },
        post: function(url, data) {
            return xhr('POST', url, data);
        }
    };

})();
```

I see that Todd Motto uses a Factory method, which I'm not familiar with. Please help me reach my .error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem is when you executing the `success` function, you only set the success callback. The error callback is overwritten by the empty placeholder function. Therefore when you are setting the `error` callback by executing the object´s `error` function, you are not calling your desired function, but the empty function.

Try this:

```
var ajax = (function() {

    var parse = function(req) {
        var result;
        try {
            result = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
        } catch (e) {
            result = req.responseText;
        }
        return [result, req];
    };

    var xhr = function(type, url, data) {
        var methods = {
            success: function(callback) {
                this.success = callback;
                return this;
            },
            error: function(callback) {
                this.error = callback;
                return this;
            }
        };
        var XHR = XMLHttpRequest || ActiveXObject;
        var request = new XHR('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
        request.open(type, url, true);
        request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState === 4) {
                if (request.status === 200) {
                    methods.success.apply(methods, parse(request));
                } else {
                    methods.error.apply(methods, parse(request));
                }
            }
        };
        request.send(data);
        return methods;
    };

    return {
        get: function(url) {
            return xhr('GET', url);
        },
        post: function(url, data) {
            return xhr('POST', url, data);
        }
    };

})();
```

Comment: Great! thanks! It seems logical, yet I don't understand why it does work in Todd Motto's setup.

Comment: This made the Atomic work for me as well. The out-of-the-box solution didn't call the error function. Thanks